# User input to text file

Tags: python, user-input

I know how to write the input to a text file (Python 2.7.x).

How would you go about having pre-written text and user input on the same line?

See:

```
f.write("Artist: ", toart + "\n")
```

The error I get is:

```
f.write("Artist: ", toart + "\n")
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `f.write("Artist: ", toart + "\n")` ==> `f.write("Artist: " + toart + "\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
f.write("Artist: " + toart + "\n")
#                 ^^^
```

This way you get only one string to be passed...